# How to pass IList value as a parameter to non IList method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have one model value

**status.cs**

```
public class statusModel
{
public string OrderNo { get; set; }
public string TicketNo { get; set; }

public IList<statusModel> statusModelList {get; set;}
}
```

I have one method

**statusChangeController.cs**

```
public class statusChangeController
{
  Public JsonResult SaveStatus(statusModel statusValue)
{
 ....
 ....
}
}
```

I am looking to pass the `IList` value into the `model` class.  I have mentioned the process below,

```
public ActionResult TransmitStatus(IList<statusModel> tranmittingData)
{
  List<statusModel> statusToUpdate = transmittingData.statusModelList.where(x=>x.public).ToList();
  statusChangeController status = new statusChangeController();
  status.SaveStatus(statusToUpdate);
}
```

How can it be achieved. I am looking for the guidance to pass the IList as paramter to non IList value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to save one statusModel or list? I guess something is wrong in your implementation

Comment: I want to save all the data in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` or [`ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) method

```
foreach (var s in statusToUpdate)
    status.SaveStatus(s);
```

Or `statusToUpdate.ForEach (x=> status.SaveStatus(x));`

You can also make a method inside controller to handle list

```
public JsonResult SaveStatus(List<statusModel> statusValue)
{
      foreach (var s in statusToUpdate)
          this.SaveStatus(s);
}
```